# Getting data from Existing ADSB Receivers

Tags: ads-b

Is there any way to get data from existing ADSB receivers installed around the world?

Comment: You mean like https://www.flightradar24.com and similar sites?

Comment: Yes , i am looking for data from their adsb recievers

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but there are services that provide data, e.g. https://www.flightradar24.com/commercial-services/data-services

Answer (score 1):

[ADSB Exchange](http://adsbexchange.com) and [OpenSky Network](https://opensky-network.org) both provide access to the data they receive from their contributors.  Terms (and payment) may vary depending on whether your use is research or commercial.